# Random, roughly even distribution of items into sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say we have an unknown number of kids who will come to compete at a quiz game. Each kid has a known overall strength rating, as well as one of four areas of focus (let's say, math, English, science or music). Teams are ideally of the fixed size four and include one individual of each area of focus, though we would never have a team of one person and we'll never turn away someone. Instead, we'd prefer to have multiple teams of three.

Can anyone help give me ideas for a strategy to achieve this? Some thoughts that haven't been fully flushed out:

- Establish the number of teams and number of people per team
- Create a random grouping with no regard to any of our desired outcome. AFTER the groupings are created, evaluate their evenness with a score. Repeat this process x times and choose the grouping that has the best score.

Alternatively, perhaps I could instead think at a more micro level when I build each team about what I need. But I would like help flushing out this idea if it seems like a reasonable one. Specifically, how to account for the team's overall score as I pick from available players, as well as how to account for remaining options (or lack thereof) for future picking rounds. Maybe I don't need to consider boxing myself into a corner, but need to reserve the option to reverse course on a previous placement.

Any thoughts would be welcome!

Comment: I think what you're doing is called "rejection sampling". You're trying out a random result, seeing if it meets your criteria, and rejecting it if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my idea.

Establish the number of teams and number of people per team. Given $n$ kids where $n \gt 5$, it is always possible to divide the kids into teams with either $3$ or $4$ members. Number the teams, starting with $1$ for the first $3$-member team (if it exists), $2$ for the second $3$-member team (if it exists), etc and moving onto the $4$-member teams when no more $3$-member teams exist.

Create $4$ arrays, one for each focus area, and place the kids in the relevant array. Sort each array so kids with the largest overall strength are on top.

Starting with team $1$:

1. Find the kid with the largest overall strength (among the $4$ arrays) who has a focus area which is not yet included in the team. Allocate this kid to the team and remove the kid from the array. (In the beginning all teams are empty, so in effect the kids are allocated only according to overall strength).
2. Determine the next team. The next team will be the team with team number $1$ higher than the previous, until the last team. When a kid has been allocated to the last team, we go backwards toward team $1$. The next team after the last team will thus be the last team again, followed by the next-to-last team, followed by the next-to-next-to-last team, etc. The allocation thus works like a sprinkler, going back and forth across the teams.
3. Go to 1, until there are no more kids.

This method should even out the overall strength for each team and also divide the focus areas evenly.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jens. Very interesting. Right off the bat, I think you're spot on with the first step: establishing the size of the teams.
I'm not entirely sure about the ordering you laid out above. If we have four teams, it sounds like you're suggesting 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 for distribution order. But Why not just use 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2? Lastly, one other challenge is I _think_ this is predictable and not random. Running the algorithm multiple times would yield identical results I believe. I'd like to be able to have multiple choices to present to the organizer.

Comment: Also, given the fact that we may not have an even distribution of specializations (maybe there are 8 students who specialize in math, but only two in English, forcing some teams to have redundant math specialists), is it possible that the algorithm will have made a decision that would force it down a path with a bad outcome, such that it would be better to backtrack? Hopefully I articulated that in a way that makes sense...

Comment: I thought your goal was to create even teams, both in regard to overall strength and in regard to distribution of focus areas. It wasn't clear from your text (at least to me) that you wanted more than one end result or that your suggestion of using a random process was mandatory. Anyway, here's a quick demo of the sprinkler allocation: If $n=16$ and all kids had the same focus area, the $4$ teams would have the following members,  ranked by overall strength: $(1,8,9,16), (2,7,10,15), (3,6,11,14), (4,5,12,13)$. We see that the sum of overall strength for each team is the same.

Comment: Sorry that my question was unclear What I'm realizing is that thinking through your response is uncovering questions that I didn't realize were there, specifically around scenarios where the input set is not ideal for creating relatively even teams. Specifically, there may not be an equal number of students with each specialty, and even if there are, they may not contain similar cumulative skill levels. I need to think about how to reconcile this. Specifically, is it better to have teams be less even but still contain one of each specialty? Anyway, thank you for your help.